# Prove that $\frac{dy}{dx} = -\frac1{(1+x)^2}$ for given that $x\sqrt{1+y} + y\sqrt{1+x} = 0$

Tags: derivatives

$$x\sqrt{1+y} + y\sqrt{1+x} = 0$$

[image: My work]

Please tell me where I went wrong. Why I am not getting correct answer ?

Comment: I suggest you write the original equation as: $$x\sqrt{1+y}=-y \sqrt{1+x}$$ then square both sides and find explicit expression for $y(x)$

Comment: You might not even have gone wrong, you can still simplify the equation by replacing $\sqrt{1+y}/\sqrt{1+x}$ by $-y/x$.

Comment: I do not see anything wrong... maybe u should use the given equation again in ur result!

Comment: There appears nothing wrong with your work, It is only that you have chosen a way that does gives you desired form of answer.

Comment: Some other posts about the same problem: [Differentiate $x \sqrt{1+y}+y \sqrt{1+x}=0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/475824) and [If $x\sqrt{1+y}+y\sqrt{1+x}=0$ find $y'$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2727358).

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong. Put the value of $y$ to get your result.

However, a simpler approach:

$$x\sqrt{1+y} + y\sqrt{1+x} = 0$$
$$x\sqrt{1+y} = - y\sqrt{1+x}$$
Squarring both sides, we get
$$x^2(1+y) =  y^2(1+x)$$
$$x^2(1+y) -  y^2(1+x)=0$$
$$(x-y)(x+y+xy)=0$$

So either $x-y=0$ or $x+y+xy=0$.

Now if, $x-y=0$, then we have $x=y$. But this does not satisfy the equation $x\sqrt{1+y} + y\sqrt{1+x} = 0$ for all $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$.

Hence required solution is $x+y+xy=0$.

Thus we can write that 
$$1+\frac{dy}{dx}+y+x\frac{dy}{dx}=0$$
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{-y-1}{1+x}=\frac{\frac{x}{1+x}-1}{1+x}=-\frac{1}{(1+x)^2}$$

Answer (score 0):

I see nothing wrong with your work....

Use the given equation in question in your result to simplify it further to get the required answer.