# Why is the possibility $x-y = 0$ rejected?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, derivatives

I'll state the question from my textbook below:

> If $x (1+y)^{1/2} + y(1+x)^{1/2} = 0$, for, $-1<x<1$, prove that
>
> $\frac{dy}{dx} = - \frac{1}{(1+x)^2}$

Here's how I tried proving it:

$x (1+y)^{1/2} + y(1+x)^{1/2} = 0$

Rearranging and squaring we get:

$x^2(1+y) = y^2(1+x)$

Simplifying and factorizing we get:

$(x+y+xy)(x-y) = 0$

Case I:

$x+y+xy = 0$

From here we get the desired equation. Since the proof is irrelevant to my question, I'll skip it. But I note that if I replace the value of $y$ I get from this equation is in harmony with the original equation given in the question.

Case II:

$x-y = 0$

Clearly in this case,

$\frac{dy}{dx} = 1$

This is where the problem arises. Isn't this a valid answer too? Probably not, because the value of $y$ I get from this equation satisfies the original equation only for $x = -1,0$. Why is this? Here are the questions I'm looking answer for:

1) Is something wrong with squaring the equation?

2) Is there a mathematical reason to reject $x-y = 0$ as a possibility?

I am also interested in alternative methods to prove the required equation. So if you have any, feel free to post them as an answer. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your equation has the form $A+B=0$. To get to the form $A^2-B^2=0$ you multiplied it by $A-B=0$ (which you disguised as squaring $A=-B$), adding with it solutions that were not solutions of the original one.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2727358/if-x-sqrt1yy-sqrt1x-0-find-y

Comment: @XanderHenderson Finding the derivative is not the point of my question. Is it still considered duplicate?

Comment: @SamInuyashaANMF Please remember that you can choose an answer among the given if the OP is solved, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On putting $y=x$, left side of equation is always positive or negative. Its satisfied only for $(0,0)$. While squaring, there may be some extra conditions introduced, which may not be satisfied by original equation.

As an example, consider the simple straight line $y=x$, squaring will give $y^2 = x^2$ or $y=\pm x$ which is a pair of straight lines.

On the other hand, if you take all things to one side so that there is $0$ on the other side, squaring is justified. That will not introduce any new roots. $y-x = 0 \iff (y-x)^2 = 0$

Answer (score 1):

We reject $x-y=0$ because then $y = x$. Now we plug this back into the original equation and find it is not a solution because, as you've stated, we don't get a true statement for all x in (-1, 1).  That is the part that is being overlooked by you.  The potential solution arising from $x -y =0$ does not satisfy the hypotheses of the original problem and therefore is not a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Let try to plug in $x=y$ in the original equation to verify that that solution doesn't work.

This means that by squaring we have obtained an extra solution to discard.

Comment: Yes, I mentioned that part. Why does it not satisfy it? I got it on squaring the very same equation, right?

Comment: @SamInuyashaANMF By squaring you have obtained an extra solution to discard.

Comment: @Sam does $(3)^2 = (-3)^2$ imply $3 = -3$?